# How do I scrape hyperlink titles using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, e-commerce

So, the website I'm trying to scrape from is: https//viewyourdeal-gabrielsimone.com'

The product names and prices are under each div class = "info-wrapper" 
I can extract the price with no problem, however when I try to extract the product title, it cannot convert it into text as its a href link. Each product name is under a div class under the href.
So my question is, how do I scrape the product name?

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 
import csv
from datetime import datetime

url = 'https://viewyourdeal-gabrielsimone.com'

gmaInfo=[]
response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
content = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
for info in content.findAll('div', attrs={"class" : "wrapper ease-animation"}):
    gridObject = {
            "title" : info.find('div', attrs={"class" : "title animation allgrey"}),
            "price" : info.find('span', attrs={"class":"red-price"}).text
            }
    print(gridObject)
    with open('index.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        writer.writerow([gridObject])
```

Comment: but the class is:  title animation allyellow

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar There's different sets I believe. What I'm trying to achieve is to get that allyellow or allgrey into a text that I can put on an xml. The class is apart of the href

Answer (score 0):

With the following code few of the items returns as None.Just provide an If condition if element exists get the text.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
from datetime import datetime

url = 'https://viewyourdeal-gabrielsimone.com'

gmaInfo=[]
response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
content = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

for info in content.findAll('div', attrs={"class" : "wrapper ease-animation"}):
   if info.find('div', attrs={"class": "title animation allgrey"}):
     gridObject = {
            "title" : info.find('div', attrs={"class" : "title animation allgrey"}).text.strip(),
            "price" : info.find('span', attrs={"class":"red-price"}).text
            }
     print(gridObject)
     with open('index.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        writer.writerow([gridObject])
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, I fixed the issue through just stating it as title instead of title animation allgrey. I was being too specific

Answer (score 0):

I was being too specific with my div class, I changed the class to simply title and it worked fine.